# Rsync on synology error

Tags: linux, rsync, synology

I have created an SSH key shared between my Synology NAS and the Debian cloud server. I created this script to synchronize two folders, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Command:**

`rsync -av --delete -e "ssh -i /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa -p 22" /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/ rsync@domain.synology.me::NetBackup/`

**Error:**

`rsync: change_dir "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/ rsync@domain.synology.me::/NetBackup" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Answer (score 2):

For a start, there shouldn't be two colons in the destination.  `rsync@domain.synology.me:/Netbackup`